# Map the physical file path in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filepath, server.mappath

I am trying to read an XSLT file from disk in my ASP.Net MVC controller. What I am doing is the following:

```
string filepath = HttpContext.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
filepath += "/Content/Xsl/pubmed.xslt";
string xsl = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
```

However, [half way down this thread on forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1201036.aspx) there is the following quote

> HttpContext.Current is evil and if you
>   use it anywhere in your mvc app you
>   are doing something wrong because you
>   do not need it.

Whilst I am not using `Current`, I am wondering what is the best way to determine the absolute physical path of a file in MVC? For some reason (I don't know why!) `HttpContext` doesn't feel right for me.

Is there a better (or recommended/best practice) way of reading files from disk in ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Xsl/"));
```

I disagree with the idea that `HttpContext.Current` is "evil." It's not the hammer for every problem, but it is certainly better than, e.g., Session for stuff that it can do OK.

Comment: Ugh! Where is `Url` defined? I added `System.Web.Mvc` to my references (and `using` statements), but it is still not defined.

Comment: It's a property of `Controller` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 15):

If you're using WebApi or not specifically within a controller class, you can use the following as an alternative:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/Xsl/pubmed.xslt")
```

Answer (score 10):

I would have the site root path injected into the controller constructor by the DI framework:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly string _siteRoot;
    public HomeController(string siteRoot)
    {
        _siteRoot = siteRoot;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_siteRoot, @"Content\Xsl\pubmed.xslt");
        return File(filePath, "text/xml");
    }
}
```

As far as the site root path is concerned it can be expressed with the [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath(v=VS.100).aspx) static property.

Comment: awesome idea!!  People should be using more IoC in applications anyway in the .NET world...we don't use it enough.