# xmltextwriter path in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmltextwriter

I am trying to use xmltextwriter and assign a path which needs to use for writing. 
I am trying this:

```
  string path = "~/Uploads/site/" + Current.User.Id + .kml";                                  
XmlTextWriter xtr = new XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

I want the file to be saved in the uploads/site/ folder within the website directory, but I am getting an error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\Uploads\site\16.kml'.
```

I would like to know how I can assign the desired path to the xmltextwriter.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use server.MapPath method to get the right path.

```
  string path =  Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/site/" + Current.User.Id + ".kml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an error

```
 string path = "~/Uploads/site/" + Current.User.Id + .kml";
```

should be

```
 string path = "~/Uploads/site/" + Current.User.Id + ".kml";
```

Still it wont work, and the answer is  illustrated in this question [Map the physical file path in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834938/map-the-physical-file-path-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: First line wouldn't even compile. so it can not be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you need to use Server.MapPath
Otherwise the code is trying to map on your pc and not the server

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/site/" + Current.User.Id + ".kml");
```